# Is it possible to remove "Case Access" column from Account Team Member add page?

Tags: account-teams

I want to remove "Case Access" column from Account Team Member add page (Kindly find the screenshot). Please help on this.

Thanks.[image]

Answer (score 0):

We can not remove Case Access column because there is no standard layout available to configure.

We can create a custom visualforce page to show the required columns and write a controller to it.